# Get IP address using domain in text file in python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file contains domains and IPs, I want to get the IP using the domain name but it returns null.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import os
import sys
import pathlib
import platform
HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
def clean_server_names(name):
    server_names_list = [x.lower().strip() for x in
                            open(HERE / "servers" / "myservers.txt", 'r').readlines()]
    for server in server_names_list:
        domain_name_and_code = server.split(' ')
        domain = domain_name_and_code[0].strip()
        ip = domain_name_and_code[-1].strip()
        if name ==  domain:
            print(ip)
clean_server_names("domain1.nordvpn.com ")
```

**Here's what inside my text file.**

```
domain1.nordvpn.com 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: pls check your if condition  `if name ==  domain:` how is the `name`  initialized ? name still contains `domain1.nordvpn.com 192.168.1.1`. so equal will not work.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: so equal operator will not work?

Comment: yes, pls. you have space in name `clean_server_names("domain1.nordvpn.com ")` see the last space after .com. so you can either remove space when you pass the parameter or strip the space ` if name.strip() ==  domain:`

Comment: I already put the strip, but still not working, Please help me

Comment: then i feel that, something different going on. pls print this line before your `if` condition.  so you know what values these variable contain. `print(f"domain=>{domain} ip=>{ip} name=>{name})")`

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of code in there that's not needed and is cluttering up what your intent is.

```
$ cat ./x.py                                                                                                                   
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-

def clean_server_names(name):
    with open("servers/myservers.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            domain_name, ip = line.lower().split()
            if name == domain_name:
                print(ip)

clean_server_names("domain1.nordvpn.com")

$ cat ./servers/myservers.txt                                                                                                  
domain1.nordvpn.com 192.168.1.1

$ ./x.py                                                                                                                       
192.168.1.1
```

Simpler:

```
$ awk '$1 == "domain1.nordvpn.com"{print $2}' servers/myservers.txt
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: still not working, but thanks for the help

Comment: it retuns like this ['\x00c\x00h\x003\x001\x008\x00.\x00n\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00v\x00p\x00n\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00', '\x008\x009\x00.\x001\x008\x007\x00.\x001\x006\x005\x00.\x003\x009\x00']
['\x00']
['\x00']

Comment: updating to show exactly what's in there and the output.